Unable to boot to Ubuntu Studio USB Stick
I created a USB boot stick with Unetbootin.   I am unable to boot into the Ubuntu Studio 24 installer.
I read that it may be UEFI vs Legacy related.  Have tried both with no success.
See attached.
enter image description here
Screenshot of boot problems
